# First time installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu instead of Win10 64bit. I have 2 hard drives, the first one is M2 128 Giga for OS, and the another one is hdd 750 Giga for storing source files and videos. Will it let me choose which one is used for the operating system or it will choose automatically? I am afraid of loosing the videos and data stored in hdd. And another question. Will I be able to see the videos and data on hdd and benefit from them?

Comment: You haven't specified what Ubuntu you are going to install (desktop, server, what release etc) so I'll be general.  I always use the "*something else*" (or *Manual Partitioning* depending on installer/release being used) option, so I have full control on how the install occurs; however it's easy to make a mistake so always do backups first. As for your videos, you've provided no details (what *file-system* are they on, what partitioning layout you have installed etc).

Comment: So, which file-system is compatible with Ubuntu? I'm going to install desktop, for programming, and my laptop dell e7510 with 16 g ram and processor ci7 6th generation with nvidia 4g

Comment: You will want to put root,(/), on the M2 128 Giga. you can have a second partition for home, (/home), it is usually ext4 and does not work on FAT32 or NTFS. if you want to put it on the hdd 750 Giga you will need to make an ext4 partition. I find it most efficient to just keep home directory part of /. You can put your data files, vacation photos, etc. on the 750. Files you are currently working on can go on the M2.

Comment: Most *file-systems* are compatible with Ubuntu (it's a list of over 40 so look it up if you want), but you're better off with a POSIX compatible file-system to ensure metadata doesn't get lost for best experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to made some assumptions in my answer, as you provided too little details about your setup. The general answer to your questions is: yes, you can choose which drive to install Ubuntu on; and yes, you will be able to keep the videos and data on your second drive and you will be able to access them from Ubuntu.

However, you must be careful when installing the system.

I **assume** that your 128G drive with OS is C: in Windows, and your 750G drive with data is D: in Windows.

When you boot from Ubuntu live DVD/USB, do not start the installation right away. Take some time to learn your current disk partition structure.

Run either "Disks" tool or GParted from the live Ubuntu system and take a look at your both disks. Your Windows drive will probably have two partitions (or maybe three, if you use UEFI for boot). Your data drive will probably have only one partition spanning the entire disk. Note the names of the partitions that the tool displays. I use here my computer as example, but your names may be different, so you need to use the actual names that the tool displays.

In my case, on first (Windows) disk there were two partitions called `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`. `/dev/sda1` was a "reserved" partition that Windows 10 uses to boot - it is usually very small; `/dev/sda2` was the actual partition corresponding to Windows C: drive that contained all the Windows files. It took the rest of the disk. The computer uses legacy mode to boot so there is no UEFI partition. I'm not sure what will be the case with UEFI - it is possible that UEFI partition will be instead of the "reserved" partition, or maybe there will be both UEFI and "reserved" partition (in that case there will be three partitions).

The other (data) disk had a single partition `/dev/sdb1`. All partitions were formatted with the NTFS file system, as this is the native file system for Windows.

If there is an UEFI partition, you need to keep it, as it is needed for the system to boot. The "reserved" partition is not needed for Ubuntu; you can delete it, and extend the "system" partition (`/dev/sda2`) with the space that was used by "reserved" partition. However, if you are unsure how to do it, you can keep the "reserved" partition - it will be unused, but it doesn't take much disk space. Note that if you delete the "reserved" partition, and resize the "system" partition, the name of the "system" partition may change - check once agaiun before starting installation.

Now start the Ubuntu installer and when the installer asks you, whether you want to replace Windows with Ubuntu, etc. select the last option - "Something else" - for custom partitioning.
Choose your "system" partition (eg. `/dev/sda2`) as a location for your root (`/`) filesystem and tell the installer to format it (you must reformat it to Linux file system, which by default is ext4).

Next, add another *mount point* and select your "data" partition (eg. `/dev/sdb2`) to be mounted at `/data` and tell the installer to **NOT** format it (since you don't want to lose the contents there). **Note:** someone already suggested to use `/home` for this partition. I'm suggesting a separate mount point `/data`, because a) you already have some contents there, and Linux during installation will by default create some contents in `/home`; and b) NTFS file system is not a very good choice for `/home` directory as it doesn't properly support Linux permissions.

The installer will also ask you (I'm not sure if this is on the same screen or on some of the next ones) where to put the *boot loader*. Choose your first drive (`/dev/sda`).

If you did everything correctly, after the installation the contents of your 750G drive should be available under the `/data` directory.

Comment: Perhaps best if Data disk is removed during installation. You can't overwrite what is not there. Personally I would format the M2 and start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a million, @C.S.Cameron for your answer. Everything is good, fortunately, I have a spare laptop that I used to try first on it. The only problem I'm facing now is the high consumption of the battery. On windows, the battery remains for 4.5 hours, but on Ubuntu it doesn't remain for 2.5 hours. How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Have you tried the Power options in settings?

Comment: Yes, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

If both hard drives are seprated but they are in one cpu than you are not gonna loose any data at all. But if you install ubuntu in 128 Giga u have to choose the something else option while installing than select \ bar in front of space where you want to install your OS. or you have one Hard Drive of 1TB then u have to choose very wisely. try this videos on youtube for more details (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7ffzC4S0A4) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-DHaQLrBi8)